Is zero in the convex hull of $3$ unit vectors iff their sum has norm at most $1$?
Let $v_i \in S^2$, for $i = 1, \dots, 3$. Consider the following statements:
(A) There exist $r_i \geq 0$, for $i = 1, \dots, 3$, not all of them zero, such that
$$ r_1 \leq r_2 + r_3 \text{ and cyclically over 1, 2 and 3}$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^3 r_i v_i = 0.$$
(B) $\lVert \sum_{i = 1}^3 v_i \rVert \leq 1.$
Are the previous two statements equivalent? I am wondering if this is so. I am trying to imagine some cases in my head, and at least for those cases, the above seem to be true.
Note: I have edited my post, due to a previous comment by @BrianMoehring, which is now deleted, which consisted of a counterexample to (B) implies (A), by choosing $v_1 = -v_2$ and then choosing $v_3$ appropriately.
Edit: I can prove that (A) implies (B). WLOG, up to relabeling the vectors and the corresponding $r_i$s and possibly rescaling the $r_i$s, one may assume that $0 < r_1 \leq r_2 \leq r_3 = 1$, say. We then have, assuming (A), that $1 \leq r_1 + r_2$ and that $r_2 \leq 1 + r_1$. Moreover, we also have
$$r_1 v_1 + r_2 v_2 + v_3 = 0.$$
Therefore
$$v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = v_1 + v_2 + v_3 - (r_1v_1 + r_2v_2 + v_3) = (1 - r_1)v_1 + (1 - r_2)v_2.$$
Hence
$$ \lVert v_1 + v_2 + v_3 \rVert \leq 2 - r_1 - r_2 \leq 1. $$
This proves that (A) implies (B).
It remains to prove/disprove the converse.

(B) doesn't imply (A).  Here's a method of constructing a counterexample:
Pick some $v_0 \in S^2$ and choose $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \{v \in S^2 : \langle v, v_0\rangle = 1/3\}$ as the vertices of an equilateral triangle.
Then we can show that $\sum_{i=1}^3 v_i = v_0$ so that (B) is satisfied, but also  $$\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^3r_iv_i, v_0\right\rangle = \frac13\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i$$
This means $\sum_{i=1}^3 r_iv_i = 0$ implies $\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i = 0$, but then if $r_i \geq 0$ for every $i$, then $r_i = 0$ for every $i$.

By the way, do you think (B) implies (A) in the planar case, i.e. assuming $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly dependent?

@Malkoun; I'll post a resolution of the planar case, showing that for that case, the answer is "yes".

In the complex plane, let $A,B,C$ be distinct points on the standard unit circle.

Claim:


If$\;|A+B+C|=1$, there exist
$r,s,t\ge 0$ such that
$$rA+sB+tC=0$$
and where$\;0 < 2\,{\cdot}\max(r,s,t)\le r+s+t$.$\\[20pt]$
If$\;|A+B+C| < 1$, there exist
$r,s,t > 0$ such that
$$rA+sB+tC=0$$
and where$\;0 < 2\,{\cdot}\max(r,s,t) < r+s+t$.


Proof:

From $|A|=1,|B|=1,|C|=1$, it follows that
$$
\overline{A}=\frac1{A}
,\;\;\;
\overline{B}=\frac1{B}
,\;\;\;
\overline{C}=\frac1{C}
$$
so we get
$$
|A+B+C|^2
=
(A+B+C)\left(\frac1{A}+\frac1{B}+\frac1{C}\right)
$$
Then for the expression $1-|A+B+C|^2$, after expanding and factoring, we get
$$
1-|A+B+C|^2
=
-\frac
{(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)}
{ABC}
\qquad(*)
$$
Consider two cases . . .

Case $(1)$:$\;|A+B+C|=1$.

Then from $(*)$ we get
$$
-\frac
{(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)}
{ABC}
=
0
$$
hence one of $A+B,B+C,C+A$ must be zero.

Without loss of generality, assume $A+B=0$.

Then letting $r=1,s=1,t=0$, we have $r,s,t\ge 0$, and
$$
rA+sB+tC=A+B=0
$$
Also, the condition
$$
0 < 2\,{\cdot}\max(r,s,t)\le r+s+t
$$
is satisfied since
$\max(r,s,t)=1$
and
$r+s+t=2$.

Thus the claim holds for case $(1)$.

Case $(2)$:$\;|A+B+C| < 1$.

Let $w$ be given by
$$
w
=
-\frac
{(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)}
{ABC}
$$
Then from $(*)$ it follows that
$w > 0$
and
$A+B,B+C,C+A$ are all nonzero.

In $\Delta ABC$, let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of sides $BC,CA,AB$, respectively.

Expressing $a^2,b^2,c^2$ in terms of $A,B,C$, we get
\begin{align*}
a^2&=\,
|B-C|^2
=
(B-C)
\left(
\frac1{B}-\frac1{C}
\right)
\\[4pt]
b^2&=\,
|C-A|^2
=
(C-A)
\left(
\frac1{C}-\frac1{A}
\right)
\\[4pt]
c^2&=\,
|A-B|^2
=
(A-B)
\left(
\frac1{A}-\frac1{B}
\right)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so then, in factored form, we get
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2-c^2&=\,
\frac
{(A+B)(B-C)(C-A)}
{ABC}
\\[4pt]
b^2+c^2-a^2&=\,
\frac
{(B+C)(C-A)(A-B)}
{ABC}
\\[4pt]
c^2+a^2-b^2&=\,
\frac
{(C+A)(A-B)(B-C)}
{ABC}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, letting
$$
v
=
(a^2+b^2-c^2)
(b^2+c^2-a^2)
(c^2+a^2-b^2)
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
&
v
=
\frac
{
(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)
(A-B)^2(B-C)^2(C-A)^2
}
{A^3B^3C^3}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{v}{w^3}
=
-\frac
{(A-B)^2(B-C)^2(C-A)^2}
{(A+B)^2(B+C)^2(C+A)^2}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{v}{w^3}
=
-u^2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where
$$
u
=
\frac
{(A-B)(B-C)(C-A)}
{(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)}
$$
Then for $\overline{u}$ we get
$$
\overline{u}
=
\frac
{
{\displaystyle{
\left(\frac1{A}-\frac1{B}\right)
\left(\frac1{B}-\frac1{C}\right)
\left(\frac1{C}-\frac1{A}\right)
}}
}
{
{\displaystyle{
\left(\frac1{A}+\frac1{B}\right)
\left(\frac1{B}+\frac1{C}\right)
\left(\frac1{C}+\frac1{A}\right)
}}
}
$$
which, after expanding and factoring, yields
$$
\overline{u}
=
-\frac
{(A-B)(B-C)(C-A)}
{(A+B)(B+C)(C+A)}
$$
Thus we have $\overline{u}=-u$, hence $u$ is pure imaginary.

Since $u$ is pure imaginary and $u\ne 0$, it follows that $u^2 < 0$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\frac{v}{w^3}=-u^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{v}{w^3} > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v > 0\qquad\bigl(\text{since $w > 0$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(a^2+b^2-c^2)
(b^2+c^2-a^2)
(c^2+a^2-b^2) > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right)
\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)
\left(\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}\right) > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\cos(\angle C)
\cos(\angle A)
\cos(\angle B) > 0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, since at least two of the three angles $A.B,C$ must be acute, it follows from the inequality
$$
\cos(\angle C),
\cos(\angle A),
\cos(\angle B) > 0
$$
that angles $A,B,C$ are all acute.

Thus $\Delta ABC$ is an acute triangle.

It follows that the circumcenter of $\Delta ABC$ lies in the interior of the triangle, hence $0$ is
a strict convex combination of $A,B,C$.

Thus there exist $r,s,t > 0$ such that $rA+sB+tC=0$.

Without loss of generality, assume $r\le s\le t$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
rA+sB+tC=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
tC=-rA-sB
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|tC| < |-rA|+|-sB|
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and where the above inequality is strict since, when regarded as vectors, no two of $A,B,C$ are parallel.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
|tC| < |-rA|+|-sB|
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t|C| < r|A|+s|B|
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t < r+s
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2t < r+s+t
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence$\;0 < 2\,{\cdot}\max(r,s,t) < r+s+t$. 

Thus the claim holds for case $(2)$.

This completes the proof.

Very nice careful analysis!

You've basically rediscovered a formula for the Atiyah determinant of 3 distinct points in Euclidean space (though the setting in my post was different).
